# Blender 2.8 material not applied to separ

Tags: modeling, materials

I have created a separate object from vertexes in an object (pressing <kbd>P</kbd> ). The object gets created but I can't seem to apply materials onto it.

The selected object ("Facade") doesn't change when different materials are added to it:

[image]

It should have a light brown color (same as the base of the building).

Comment: Since the facade is now a separate object, it doesn't need all those other materials in your list and is probably applying the first one - try (1) removing all except the one you want to apply or (2) go into edit mode, select all faces and press 'assign' with the material you want applied.

Comment: Tried unlinking all materials, relinking the material I wanted and created a separate material altogether. All failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to change the material by selecting faces (Ctrl + L does this more quickly). Click assign after selecting faces and changing material.

I sometimes manage to create a new object from vetexes and then assign a material to it. Sometimes, I can't. I really have no clue as to why.